# use .my.cnf for ruby mysql connection

Tags: mysql, ruby, passwords

In a ruby script (not rails) Iam using mysql. Because my mysql are available in a .my.cnf file, I can use mysql on the terminal without password. But that does not work in a ruby script, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2), you may need to read  the `.my.conf` manually, as show in the doc

> Reading a MySQL config file
>
> You may read configuration options from a MySQL configuration file by
>   passing the :default_file and :default_group parameters. For example:
>
> Mysql2::Client.new(:default_file => '/user/.my.cnf', :default_group =>
>   'client')